# Bus Report System with Destination-Specific Embeds

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot that allows users to submit bus reports, and I need some assistance with the interaction process. The goal is to have a dynamic system where users can select different destinations from the first dropdown menu and then choose the number of drivers from the second dropdown menu. Based on their selections, the bot should send a corresponding embed with the selected destination and the number of drivers.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, SelectMenuBuilder  } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('bus-test')
    .setDescription('Just testing')
    .addAttachmentOption(option => option.setName('screenshot').setDescription('Upload a screenshot').setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('other_drivers').setDescription('Enter all drivers with @').setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('passengers').setDescription('Enter all passengers with @').setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const author = interaction.user;
    const drivers = interaction.options.getString('other_drivers');
    const passengers = interaction.options.getString('passengers');
    const attachment = interaction.options.get('screenshot').value;

    const passengersWithDots = passengers.split(' ').map(passenger => `• ${passenger}`).join('\n');
    const driversWithDots = drivers.split(' ').map(driver => `• ${driver}`).join('\n');
    const driversWithMention = `• ${author}\n${driversWithDots}`;

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('**Report System Rules**')
      // .setColor('YELLOW')
      .setDescription(`${driversWithMention}\n\nPassenger(s)\n${passengersWithDots}`)
      .setImage(attachment.url);

    const destinationmenu = new SelectMenuBuilder()
      .setCustomId('destination_menu')
      .setPlaceholder('Select destination')
      .addOptions([
        {
          label: 'Option 1',
          value: 'option_1',
        },
        {
          label: 'Option 2',
          value: 'option_2',
        },
      ]);

    const drivermenu = new SelectMenuBuilder()
      .setCustomId('drivernum_menu')
      .setPlaceholder('Select number of drivers')
      .addOptions([
        {
          label: '1 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_1',
        },
        {
          label: '2 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_2',
        },
        {
          label: '3 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_3',
        },
        {
          label: '4 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_4',
        },
        {
          label: '5 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_5',
        },
        {
          label: '6 driver(s)',
          value: 'driver_num_6',
        },
      ]);

    const Preview = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('Preview_button')
      .setLabel('Preview')
      .setStyle('Primary');

    const Cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('Cancel_button')
      .setLabel('Cancel')
      .setStyle('Danger');

    const row1 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(destinationmenu);
    const row2 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(drivermenu);
    const row3 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(Cancel, Preview);

    const reply = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      ephemeral: true,
      components: [row1, row2, row3],
    });

    const message = interaction.isMessageComponent() ? interaction.message : reply;
    const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 30000 });

    collector.on('collect', async (buttonInteraction) => {
      if (buttonInteraction.user.id === interaction.user.id) {
        if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'Preview_button') {
          if (buttonInteraction.values && buttonInteraction.values.length >= 2) {
            const selectedDestination = buttonInteraction.values[0];
            const selectedDriverNum = buttonInteraction.values[1];
    
            // Check which option was selected and create a corresponding embed
            let newEmbed;
            if (selectedDestination === 'option_1' || selectedDestination === 'option_2') {
              // Get the label of the selected driver number option
              const selectedDriverLabel = driverMenu.options.find(option => option.value === selectedDriverNum).label;    
            newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Preview')
              .setColor('GREEN')
              .setDescription(`Selected Destination: ${selectedDestination}\nSelected Driver(s): ${selectedDriverLabel}`)
              .setImage(attachment.url);
          } else {
            // Handle the case if no valid option was selected
            newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Invalid Selection')
              .setDescription('Please select a valid option.')
              .setColor('RED');
          }

          // Update the original embed with the new one
          await buttonInteraction.update({
            embeds: [newEmbed],
            components: [],
          });
        } else if (buttonInteraction.customId === 'Cancel_button') {
          await buttonInteraction.update({
            content: 'Report canceled.',
            embeds: [],
            components: [],
          });
        }
      }
    }});

    collector.on('end', async () => {
      // Remove the original embed and components after the collector ends
      await message.edit({
        content: 'This report is no longer active.',
        embeds: [],
        components: [],
      });
    });
  },
};
```

What I need help with is updating the destinationMenu to include additional destination options. When a user selects a specific destination, I want the bot to display an embed that includes both the selected destination and the number of drivers they previously chose from the driverMenu. For example, if a user chooses "Option 1" from the destination menu and "2 drivers" from the driver menu, the bot should send an embed like:
every destination have it is own embed with its own images in the embed but the same in all embeds is driver number like

```
Selected Destination: Option 1
Selected Driver(s): 2 driver(s)
```

If anyone could help me with this dynamic interaction process, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Please note the following:**

1. **ButtonInteraction**s do not have `values`! [Learn more..](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ButtonInteraction)
2. Make sure to add a [ComponentType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ComponentType) check in your `collect` event
3. Please use proper name conventions
4. `SelectMenuBuilder` is deprecated, use [StringSelectMenuBuilder](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/StringSelectMenuBuilder) instead
5. `MessageEmbed` is a discord.js v13 class, your code is mostly v14, so use [EmbedBuilder](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/EmbedBuilder) instead

#### Fixes

```js
const { ComponentType } = require("discord.js");
// ...
collector.on("collect", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.type === ComponentType.Button) {
        // handle button click events here
    } else if (interaction.type === ComponentType.StringSelect) {
        // handle string select menu events here
    }
})
```

- Other changes:

```
// change this
newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
// to this
newEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()

// and this
const drivermenu = new SelectMenuBuilder()
// to this
const drivermenu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
```